# R and GO.db: go through all GO terms

Tags: r, bioconductor

This is a very specific question, but maybe someone here knows how to do it.

What I want is to go through all GO terms from an ontology such as "BP" (package GO.db). I do not necessarily want to go recursively through the tree, the only requirement I have on the order of evaluation of the GO terms is that for a given GO term, all it's children have been evaluated before that GO term.

In other words, I want to construct a character vector V of GO terms such as if G_x and G_y are two GO terms, and G_x is the parent of G_y, then the indices i_x and i_y of position of these GO terms in V are such that i_x > i_y.

Comment: As a partial answer, `g = makeGOGraph("bp")` creates a graphNEL (from package graph) of the BP ontology; `library(RBGL); dfs(g)` returns indexes for a depth-first search; maybe this provides the information you need?

Answer (score 1):

I think this (almost) works. The trick with this is that `?unique` keeps the first instance of a duplicated element.

Edit: Upon reflection, this is only organizing terms with the longest path to the root (i.e. with the most generations) at the beginning of the vector. I think there could be a case where a term is on two branches, one with a shorter path, where the term would be correctly placed for the long path, but is placed to early for the shorter path. That said, if you're ok with a rough approximation...

```
# Root nodes for reference:
# BP = "GO:0008150"
# CC = "GO:0005575"
# MF = "GO:0003674"

GO_order <- function(node = "GO:0008150", ontology = "BP") {

    if (ontology == "BP") GOCHILDREN <- GOBPCHILDREN
    if (ontology == "CC") GOCHILDREN <- GOCCCHILDREN
    if (ontology == "MF") GOCHILDREN <- GOMFCHILDREN

    parents <- node

    # initialize output
    out <- c(parents)

    # do the following until there are no more parents
    while (any(!is.na(parents))) {  
        # Get the unique children of the parents (that aren't NA)
        children <- unique(unlist(mget(parents[!is.na(parents)], GOCHILDREN)))

        # append chldren to beginning of `out`
        # unique will keep the first instance of a duplicate 
        # (i.e. the most recent child is kept)
        out <- unique(append(children[!is.na(children)], out))

        # children become the parents of the next generation
        parents <- children
    }
    return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the internal function of GO.db

```
GO_child <- function(node = "GO:0008150", ontology = "BP") {
  #MF = "GO:0003674", node of MF
  #BP = "GO:0008150", node of BP
  #CC = "GO:0005575", node of CC
  if (ontology == "BP") res <- GOBPOFFSPRING[[node]]
  if (ontology == "CC") res <- GOCCOFFSPRING[[node]]
  if (ontology == "MF") res <- GOMFOFFSPRING[[node]]
  return(res)
}
```